# Pandas TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to create a `pandas` DataFrame from a `query_set.QuerySet` object but when I go for:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res)
```

`res` being the query set, I get the following error:

```py
TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable.
```

What can I do to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's Django's QuerySet you can use the following code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res.values())
```

`queryset.values()` returns list of dicts.

You can find more information at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values) link.